# Storybook/HTML for Addon-Docs

Tags: storybook

How can I add docs in 'mdx' format for my storie in Storybook/HTML? How can i connect my example.stories.js with example.stories.mdx, how example.stories.mdx should look like? On official documentation there is an example for React but I can`t find some guide dedicated for Storybook/HTML.

Answer (score 5):

The key is to write the stories and docs separately, embedding the stories in the docs using their IDs (an ID of a story can be found in the URL, something like `stories--story`).

Let's say you have this `index.stories.js` file:

```js
import docs from './docs.mdx';  // this import is important

export default {
  title: 'Demo',
  parameters: {  // specify the docs MDX content here
    docs: {
      page: docs, 
    }
  }
};

export const Heading = () => '<h1>Hello World</h1>';

export const Button = () => {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.type = 'button';
  btn.innerText = 'Hello Button';
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e));
  return btn;
};
```

And the corresponding `docs.mdx` file would contain embedded stories:

```
import { Story, Preview } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';

# Index

Writing `Markdown` here:

<Preview>
  <Story id="demo--heading" />
  <Story id="demo--button" />
</Preview>

And an individual story:

<Story id="demo--heading" />
```

Learn more:

- [MDX reference](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/addons/docs/docs/mdx.md#embedding-stories) on embedding stories
- [Installation requirements for MDX](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/docs#installation)